# How to select the particular value by trigger()

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

In the Jquery slider ,minimum value is 1 and maximum value is 100

Here ,current value is 30, and i have to select the value to 50 
This should be doneby programatically like using trigger() or any other similar methods.

How to do this?

Comment: i have to do this using trigger method.

Comment: Where do you want to use `trigger` ? It would be better if you shared your code and explain.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the slider value to 30 like:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 30 );
```

More information at [slider API docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-value).

Answer (score 1):

Refer Jquery UI Docs [JQuery Doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/)

Have you tried something like this :

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 30 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the value anytime other than initialization

```
$( ".selector" ).slider( "value", 30);
```

[JQuery Slider Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value)